# Remover strings con menos de 5 caracteres en python

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente codigo, mi intencion es eliminar las lineas de un string cuyas lineas tengan menos de 5 caracteres pero contando solos numero, letras y simbolos, el problema es que me toma tambien los espacios:

```
s="I I  \n1\nO O  \n123456"  
nueva = "\n".join([i for i in s.split('\n') if len(i) < 5])
print("Linea original:\n",s)
print ("linea nueva:\n",nueva)
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes volver a usar split para dividir las oraciones en palabras y contar su contenido sin los espacios.

```
s="I I  \n1\n1 2 3 4\n1 2 3 4 5\n123456\n"  
nueva = "\n"
for i in s.split('\n'):
  largo = 0
  for j in i.split(' '):
    largo += len(j)
  if (largo >= 5):
    nueva+= "\n" + i

print("Linea original:\n",s)
print ("linea nueva:\n",nueva)
```

```
largo = 0
```

Esta variable lleva la cuenta de palabras de la línea.

```
for j in i.split(' '):
    largo += len(j)
```

Incrementamos su valor con el largo de cada oración en la línea.

```
if (largo >= 5):
    nueva+= "\n" + i
```

Al final se evalúa si el largo total sin espacios es igual o mayor que cinco.

Resultado:

```
Linea original:
 I I
1
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
123456

linea nueva:


1 2 3 4 5
123456
```